# How can I make a PUT request to Trello API in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trello, net-http, http-put

The following code doesn't work as whished (ie. the card is not moving to the desired column id) due to an error.

```
require 'net/http'

    http = Net::HTTP.new('api.trello.com')
    response = http.send_request('PUT', '/1/cards/xxxxxxcardidherexxxxxx?key=xxxxxxkeyherexxxxxx&token=xxxxxxtokenherexxxxxx&idList=xxxxxxtargettedlistidherexxxxxx')
```

Error received:

```
=> #<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>
```

Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: Can you please try to add https://. http = Net::HTTP.new('https://api.trello.com')

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a HTTP library such as HTTParty instead. Net::HTTP is very low level and clunky (it's the worst part of the ruby standard lib) and you're going to have to do a lot more work to send a request via `https`.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 Moved Permanently status tells you that the resource has been moved to another URL. The URL can be found in the location header in the response. I made a request to the endpoint you provided and got this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< location: https://api.trello.com/1/actions/id?key=APIKey&token=APIToken
< date: Mon, 30 Oct 2023 07:55:53 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
```

Here you can see that that the host is not `api.trello.com` but `https://api.trello.com`.

So instead of using `http = Net::HTTP.new('api.trello.com')`, please use either Net::HTTP with extra steps for SSL connections or another request library that is not as low level as `Net::HTTP`, e.g `HTTParty`.

Comment: There are quite a few more steps involved than just changing the URI if you want to do TLS with Net::HTTP.

Comment: You are right @max. Let me clarify this in my answer. Thanks for pointing out :)